# Rails returning strange invalid information in view but not console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I know for a fact (having checked through the console) that the output should be three songs, but for some reason I keep getting a fourth song added to every page. The song is different on every occasion, and I'm baffled as to why this is happening. Any help is much appreciated!

In my controller

```
  def edit
    @songs = Song.all(order: 'title')
    @song = Song.find(params[:id])
    @setlist = Setlist.find(params[:id])
    @allocations = @setlist.allocations
  end
```

The full view code, as requested:

First the view for the actual edit page:

```
<h1>Edit a Setlist</h1>
<div class="row">
   <div class="span8">
      <%=form_for(@setlist) do|f|%>

         <%=f.label :date, "Set a date" %>
         <span><%=f.date_select :date%><span>

         <%=f.label :morning, "Morning" %>
         <%=f.radio_button :morning, true %>
         <%=f.label :morning, "Evening" %>
         <%=f.radio_button :morning, false %>

         <h2>Library</h2>   

        <div>
          <%= render 'library' %>
          <%= render 'currentSet' %> 
        </div>

         <%=f.submit "Save Setlist", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
      <% end %>
   </div>
</div>
```

The current set partial (ignore the library partial, as it's a nested form with nothing added yet):

```
<div id="currentSet">
   <h2>Current Setlist</h2>
     <table class= "table table-striped table-bordered">
       <thead>
         <th>Title</th>
         <th>Artist</th>
         <th>Root Key</th>
         <th>Remove</th>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
         <% if(@allocations.empty?) %>
            <tr><td>NO SONGS</td></tr>
         <% else %>
            <%= render @allocations %>
         <%end%>    
      </tbody>
     </table>
   </div>
```

And allocations:

```
<tr>
    <td><%= allocation.song.title %></td>
    <td><%= allocation.song.artist %></td>
    <td><%= allocation.song.key %></td>
    <td><%= link_to "Remove Song", allocation, method: :delete %></td>
</tr>
```

I'm not sure if this is relevant but I've also added the actual rendered html for examination:

```
<tr>
    <td>S</td>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>K</td>
    <td><a href="/allocations/7" data-method="delete" rel="nofollow">Remove Song</a>...
</tr><tr>
    <td>S</td>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>K</td>
    <td><a href="/allocations" data-method="delete" rel="nofollow">Remove Song</a></td>
</tr>
```

The part I'm finding wierd is that the last entry differs from all the others in that the url doesn't have an allocation id i.e. /allocations/9 in the second last one vs /allocations in the last one.

Comment: Where are you telling it to show three songs and not four? I don't see any loops. Does the database only have three songs? How then are you getting a fourth?

Comment: I'm telling it to show all songs which have been allocated to the setlist. However I know for a fact that the database only has three songs assigned (I have confirmed this using the console) per setlist.

Comment: `s.allocations.count
   (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "allocations" WHERE "allocations"."setlist_id" = 1
 => 3`

Comment: Can you give us the full view code?

Comment: Sure thing, give me two ticks to get it organized.

Comment: This might not be related, but why do you use the same :id in the finder for Song and Setlist in your controller method?

Comment: That turned out to be the issue. Just managed to figure it out. Thanks very much for the help everyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to close this one off then:

```
  def edit
    @songs = Song.all(order: 'title')
    @song = Song.find(params[:id])
    @setlist = Setlist.find(params[:id])
    @allocations = @setlist.allocations
  end
```

Use the appropriate :id's in your Song and Setlist finders (i.e. not the same one).